# Multiple desktops / multiple wallpapers

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-background, multiple-desktops

I've been running Kubuntu 14.04 because it provides multiple desktops, each with its own wallpaper.  Newer versions of Kubuntu/KDE have gone activity-based and this facility is no longer there.  It is apparently possible to simulate it with activities, but very awkwardly.

Kubuntu 14.04 has a limited lifetime; it will no longer be maintained in a couple of years.  So my question is: are there any other Linux environments that provide multiple desktops with individualized wallpaper?

Comment: I use Xfce4 (Xubuntu) where it's not as flashy as KDE (Kubuntu) is, but it supports individual wallpapers, etc.

Comment: as far as I know, a compiz plugin provides that feature but without desktop icons.